# Set the onLocationChanged to a specific longitude and latitude and zoom it in

Tags: java, android

When I run this code the map loads. However it is extremly zoomed out even though I set it to `setZoom(20)`. (No matter what I set it to, it still doesn't change.)
Instead of this I want to set the location to the user's current location and if not then I want to set the location myself by using geoPoint.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.Location;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.osmdroid.util.GeoPoint;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;
import org.osmdroid.tileprovider.tilesource.TileSourceFactory;


public class HelloMap extends Activity {

MapView mv;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater lf, ViewGroup vg, Bundle b)
{
    View view = lf.inflate(R.layout.content_hello_map, vg, false);
    mv = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map1);
    mv.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    mv.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mv.getController().setZoom(20);
    mv.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(20, -20));
    return view;
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_map);
    LocationManager mgr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener Locat= new mylocationlistener();
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        return;
    }
    mgr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, Locat);
}

private class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

            Toast.makeText(HelloMap.this,
                    location.getLatitude() + "" + location.getLongitude(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: after requestLocationUpdates If location did not change, then you can call getLastKnownLocation(String) and retrieve the location immediately and set it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `CameraUpdateFactory` with method `newLatLngZoom(LatLng latLng, float zoom)`.
For example:

```
LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(lat, lng);
CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 5);
map.animateCamera(yourLocation);
```